# Display all rows of gcloud <servicename> jobs list output

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have more than thousand records in my `GCP dataflow Jobs` console .  When I display these records using `gcloud dataflow jobs list` it displays only 104 records

```
  $ gcloud dataflow jobs list --region europe-west1 --format=[no-heading] | wc -l
   104
```

Any way to display all records from `gcloud` output ? I tried with --page-size but it is displaying 100 records only

```
  gcloud dataflow jobs list --region europe-west1 --page-size=1000 | wc -l
  101

 $ gcloud dataflow jobs list --region europe-west1 --page-size=200 | wc -l
 101
```

I am doing some processing on the output of `gcloud` command but since number of rows is more than 1000 I want to display all rows at one go so that it becomes easy for me to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `--limit` flag. It represents the maximum number of resources to list. The default value is 100. This flag interacts with other flags that are applied in this order: `--flatten`, `--sort-by`, `--filter`, `--limit`. You can refer more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list).